# Share 4G USB Internet on Raspberry Pi 4 over WiFi and Ethernet

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, hotspot

I've already set up my RPi 4 as a hotspot using dnsmasq and hostapd, using a USB 4G modem to connect to the internet.  This is working as expected, I'm able to connect other devices to it and get network and internet access.

What I am trying to do is *also* share the USB internet through the ethernet port, so that I can hook up a RPi 3+ that way (WiFi on this board doesn't appear to work), both while being on the same network, ideally.

Is this possible?

Comment: Tell us how you configure *a hotspot using dnsmasq and hostapd*. || Has the connected 4G USB device made a new interface on `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to forward traffic from the wired interface (eth0?) to the **usb0** interface. Because you do not have provided any details about your network configuration I can only guess. You have to enable **ip forwarding**. There are several ways to do it: within `/etc/sysctl.conf` or by `systemd-networkd` or with `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. Because you have already a working access point with uplink to your 4G modem, ip forwarding should already be enabled. Check if `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns **1**. If so the wired connection could already work. Just try it.

If you are using a bridge instead of routing with enabled ip forwarding then you have to add the wired interface as additional slave to the bridge.